# Bounding integral with quadratic complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, statistical-mechanics

I am reading [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0087664.pdf) book (Euclidean Harmonic Analysis, Benedetto, 1979) and on pages 24-25 Carleson proves a lemma related to the Kolmogorov-Seliverstov-Plessner method. There is one small step in bounding a Fourier-transform-esque integral that he takes as trivial, but I cannot seem to figure out how he came to the conclusion. Namely, on the first line of p. 25 he states that if $|A|\leq 2$ and we take $0<\alpha<1$ then the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(2At+t^2)}\frac{dt}{|t|^{\alpha}}$$ is bounded. This seems logical, but I am unsure what the standard approach to bounding such integrals is (do we use Contour integration? Some sort of analytic argument involving cancellation?). Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Split the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(2At+t^2)}\frac{dt}{|t|^{\alpha}}=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}+ \int_{-1}^1+\int_1^\infty$$
Evidently, $\int_{-1}^1$ exists and is bounded. For $\int_1^\infty$ you can use the Dirichlet’s Test for Improper Integrals ( https://mathsci.kaist.ac.kr/~kdryul/files/articles/Dirichlet's%20Test%20for%20Improper%20Integrals.pdf ):
$\,\,\int_1^x e^{i(2At+t^2)}dt$ is bounded for any $x\in[1;\infty],\,\, \frac{1}{t^\alpha}\to0$ and $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{t^\alpha}<0$. For $\int_{-\infty}^{-1}$ make the substitution $s=-t$ and use again the Dirichlet’s Test.